# Separate for negative values in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have values of a time series in one column for example: YYYY/mm/dd Tmin, where (Tmin) minimum temperature is in some cases negative. When I use the separate function it works well but my problem is that it removes the negative sign from the Tmin.

This is what I have in one column:

```
 1951   1   27   -1.2
 1951   1   28   0.32
 1951   1   29   1.89
 1951   1   30   2.95
```

I tried the function separate but it doesn't keep the sign of the last values and produces this

```
1951   1   27   1.2
1951   1   28   0.32
1951   1   29   1.89
1951   1   30   2.95
```

```
new_df=separate(df,"c1",c("y","m","d","v"),
sep = "[^[:alnum:]]+",extra="merge",convert = TRUE)
```

What I want is to keep the sign of all of them. Something like this

```
   y    m    d     v
 1951   1   27   -1.2
 1951   1   28   0.32
 1951   1   29   1.89
 1951   1   30   2.95
```

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Could you also copy and paste your expected output?

Comment: Of course, sorry for that.

Comment: Just change sep to `sep="\\s+`

Comment: Maybe just do: `read.table(text="copy and paste your text here" )`or  just read your file with separator set to `" "` or `\\s`??

Comment: The ```sep="\\s+"``` worked perfectly thanks a lot!!! A. Suliman